# Use of extends keyword in generics

Tags: java, generics

I am trying this -

```
List<? extends Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
l.add(10);
```

and compiler says -

```
The method add(int, capture#1-of ? extends Integer) in the type List<capture#1-of ? extends Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (int)
```

---

Why i am not able to add an integer to a List of Integer, Why compiler is not complaining at first line itself if i will not be able to add integers?

Comment: `List<? extends Integer>` is NOT `List<Integer>`. Take a look at [PECS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2723397/2775450)

Comment: @Codebender.. correct. as per PECS, if i replace extends with super, this'll work.  But why compiler is not complaining at first line itself.

Comment: `l.add(new Integer(10))` should work though, right? Might be that autoboxing is turned off..

Comment: @Kenney No, That wont work

Comment: @MohammadAdil, Because an `ArrayList<Integer>` is a valid object (subtype) for `List<? extends Integer>`. So your first line is valid...

Comment: The only thing you can add to it is `null`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`List<? extends Integer>` denotes a list of some *unknown* type that extends `Integer`. Forgetting for the moment that `Integer` is `final`, at runtime it could be a list of some subtype `MyImaginaryInteger`, in which case you cannot add the `Integer` 10 since that would break the type safety. That's why the compiler does not allow you to add elements.

On the other hand, `List<? super Integer>` denotes a list of some unknown type that is a parent class of `Integer`. In this case, adding the `Integer` value 10 is OK because regardless of what that type is at runtime, `Integer` is a subtype of it.

In your specific case, there's no point in having this wildcard at all -- just declare it as `List<Integer>`.

Comment: Well in that case, will i be able to add `MyImaginaryInteger` to `List<? extends Integer>`

Comment: No because it could be a `List<MyOtherImaginaryInteger>`.